# Correct Linq conversion from C# to Vb.net

Tags: c#, vb.net, linq

I am looking for an accurate conversion of this C# Linq code to VB.net. I have tried a number of tools to convert the C# to VB, but none of the VB converted statements return the correct results.

C#

```
 var rows = GridView1.Rows.Cast<GridViewRow>().Where(a => a != row).ToList();
```

VB.net

```
 Dim rows = GridView1.Rows.Cast(Of GridViewRow)().Where(Function(a) a IsNot row).ToList()
```

The process is suppose to select the rows of a Gridview, excluding the row selected by a click.
All rows are return, no row is excluded...

C#

```
Button btnUp = (Button)sender;
GridViewRow row = (GridViewRow)btnUp.NamingContainer;
 // Get all items except the one selected
var rows = GridView1.Rows.Cast<GridViewRow>().Where(a => a != row).ToList();
```

VB.net

```
Dim btnUp As Button = DirectCast(sender, Button)
Dim row As GridViewRow = DirectCast(btnUp.NamingContainer, GridViewRow)
' Get all items except the one selected
Dim rows = GridView1.Rows.Cast(Of GridViewRow)().Where(Function(a) a IsNot row).ToList()
```

Thanks for any and all help.

Comment: Can you clarify in what way the results are not correct? Do they return the selected row? do they filter out too many rows? do they just return the row you want filtered, etc. I'd have guesssed that `a <> row` woudl be better than `a isnot row` but the subtleties of vb.net are sometimes beyond me...

Comment: Have you tried? http://www.developerfusion.com/tools/convert/csharp-to-vb

Comment: are your casts correct? are you sure you have that instance of row in the rows property?

Comment: All rows are return, no row is excluded.

Comment: @Nathan yes I have tried that converter as well.

Comment: there's nothing wrong with your code syntactically..so it must be something logically...debug it and make sure that row is actually in the initial collection.

Comment: I have and it is, I even added code to check the selected index and it is being identified.

Comment: You could use the selected index to identify the row to exclude.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
Dim btnUp As Button = DirectCast(sender, Button)
Dim row As GridViewRow = DirectCast(btnUp.NamingContainer, GridViewRow)
Dim rows = GridView1.Rows.Cast(Of GridViewRow)().Where(Function(a) a <> row).ToList()
```

Comment: IsNot is perfectly valid as it does a reference equality check.

Comment: <> does not work.  ****  Error 73 Overload resolution failed because no accessible 'Where' can be called with these arguments: